# Do armed zombies deal normal damage or sword damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When a zombie in minecraft is wielding a sword does the zombie hurt you with the equivalent damage of the sword or just his bare hands?

Comment: i dont mean to be horribly rude, but your aware that this question could have been self answered with a simple wiki visit?

Comment: where in the wiki does it answer me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Armed_Zombie) they deal damage depending on which item they are holding and it's enchantments.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** Zombies with swords hit you with sword damage.